# Using open source PKCS#11 library for a token?

Tags: pkcs#11

I have been learning about PKCS#11 and now I want to create some applications using it in C. Now I have the following question,

1) I think the shared library for a token comes with vendor of the token, Am I right?

2) Which open source library for PKCS#11 (in C) I can use if I have a token and not the its shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I think the shared library for a token comes with vendor of the token, Am I right?

Yes in most cases it does.

> 2) Which open source library for PKCS#11 (in C) I can use if I have a token and not the its shared library?

[OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC) project ships PKCS#11 library which supports [several cards and tokens](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-(smart-cards-and-USB-tokens)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I have noticed that the examples in opensc-pkcs11 lib don't use API functions and data types listed in RSA standard of PKCS#11 ?

Comment: @PrateekJoshi can you please provide a link to those examples that "don't use API functions and data types listed in RSA standard of PKCS#11"?

Comment: In the sample program https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11/blob/master/examples/auth.c , they have used data types like PKCS11_SLOT and functions like PKCS11_enumerate_slots() , but such data types and functions are not a part of PKCS#11 RSA standard (https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/STANDARD/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf).

Comment: @PrateekJoshi [libp11](https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11) is standalone convenience wrapper library built on top of  standard PKCS#11 API so naturally it is using it's own structures in its examples. Source code of PKCS#11 library `opensc-pkcs11.dll` shipped by OpenSC project is [located in different repository](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/tree/master/src/pkcs11)